# How to implement =Lookup function in VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following table:

[image: Lookup Function]

the lookup funcion in my case gives me the dates (06/08/2018) rate of 3.5% as this date falls in between the dates in the lookup table. I am struggling to produce same function in vba.

```vb
Function GetDateRate(dateValue As Date, dateRange As Range, valuesRange As Range)

    GetCurrentRate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(2, 1 / (dateRange <= dateValue), valuesRange)

End Function
```

But unfortunatly it fails... how can I fix that?

Comment: Use `Evaluate`. The `WorksheetFunction` won't be able to handle the boolean array `Table1[Date]<=E5`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the problem:

[image]

```
    Set d = Range("G2")
Set TABLERANGE = Range("$D$2:$E$8") ' range of the table to explore

Range("H2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(d, TABLERANGE, 2, True)
```

Comment: No I need to keep percentages as percentages and dates as dates unfortunately

Comment: Now percentges are kept.